# How to add values dynamically to I18n?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, translation, rails-i18n

I have many ymls in my rails app, and i want to put some of them in other service, so that i can call this from multiple places.
the response of this call will be a hash.

```
{"en" : 
  {"test" : 
    {"text1" : "hi english"},
    {"text2" : "mambo number %{num}"}
  },
 "es" : 
  {"test" : 
    {"text1" : "hi espaniol"},
    {"text2" : "mamboes numeros %{num}"}
  }
}
```

is there a way i can load that hash into `I18n` translations 
like

```
I18n.add_translations(some_hash)
```

so i can access them with

```
I18n.t("test.text1")
I18n.t("test.text2", :num => 5)
```

how can i achieve it?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**The dirty way**

You could override the `load_translation` method in I18n::Backend::Base through a custom module or gem or -- cough -- monkey patching -- cough -- to fetch the translations from different sources, it feels dirty to me but I guess you could try experimenting with that before going further.

https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/backend/base.rb#L13

**Changing the I18n Backend**

You can create a different I18n Backend that implements the expected behaviour and hook it up to I18n through an initializer. I'm assuming that's how tools like localeapp and phraseapp do it. There is a method just for that in I18n::Config

https://github.com/svenfuchs/i18n/blob/master/lib/i18n/config.rb#L23

So you can just do this in an initializer

```
I18n.backend = MyAwesomeI18nBackend.new
```

The good thing is that you can chain multiple backends together

```
I18n.backend = I18n::Backend::Chain.new(MyAwesomeI18nBackend.new)
```

It makes sure you still have access to the default translation backends or other custom backends.

**References**

Ryan made a great railscast back in the days explaining how to change backends. It's a bit outdated but it gives you a good idea of what needs to be done.

[I18n Backends](http://railscasts.com/episodes/256-i18n-backends)

If your translations are related to some data saved in a database, you could also use globalize to handle those.

https://github.com/globalize/globalize

**EDIT: Simpler way by Dima**

If you have a hash, you can use the default backend's `store_translation` method to load translations from that hash.

```
I18n.backend.store_translations(:en, {test: "YOOOOOHHHHHOOOO"})
```

Comment: Cool, i found from your references `I18n.backend.store_translations(:en, {test: "YOOOOOHHHHHOOOO"})`
 it worked

Comment: Indeed, that's another way to do it if you already have the hash and don't want to build a whole backend. I'm going to add it to my answer for clarity if you don't mind.